# php multidimensional SplFixedArray declaration is throwing fatal error

Tags: php, arrays

I want to declare SplFixedArray(); to save memory consumption. but it is throwing fatal error.

```
$items=new SplFixedArray();
echo "Array Started...";
    for($h=0;$h<5000;$h++)
    {   
        for($i=0;$i<24;$i++)
        {   
            $items[$h][$i]=$objSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$h+1)->getValue();
        }
    }
```

The same is working if do not declare `new SplFixedArray();`

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Index
>   invalid or out of range' in /home/twa/files.php:168 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/twa/files.php(168): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/twa/files.php on line 168

`$items=new SplFixedArray(SplFixedArray());` is also failing...

Please let me know correct syntax...

Comment: You are not specifying the size `new SplFixedArray();` what values for `$h` and `$i` have?

Comment: @cornelb : h=5000 & i =30 ; Question modified accordingly

Comment: can you paste the loop code too?

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all - if no value is passed to the constructor of `SplFixedArray`, the documentation suggests it is given a size of 0.

Comment: @cornelb : Please see my updated question with loop

Comment: I also updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$items = new SplFixedArray(5000);
for ($h=0; $h<5000; $h++) {
    $items[$h] = new SplFixedArray(24);
    for ($i=0; $i<24; $i++) {
        $items[$h][$i] = $objSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$h+1)->getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: After h=720, It says `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Index invalid or out of range' in /home/twa/files.php:166 Stack trace: #0 /home/twa/files.php(166): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in /home/twa/files.php on line 166`

Comment: testing with something like `$items[$h][$i] = rand(0,3000)` works. What kind of values are you getting from `$objSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$h+1)->getValue()` ?

Comment: its a string . is it possible to clear array memory after every 500 iteration so that i wont face memory issue

Comment: have you tried normal arrays before `SplFixedArray`? Maybe that works too

Comment: i faced similar issue in normal array. so wanted to use splfixedarray to save memory..

Comment: what are you doing with the values after you put them in `$items`? Maybe you can take 1000 rows at a time, process them, then `unset($items)` and star the next 1000-item batch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48141/discussion-between-logan-and-cornelb)

Comment: i am storing the values into database;